# A workflow with bookdown to produce frequency, cross tables and model summary tables

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am starting to write a book using bookdown and trying to find the best workflow. First of all I am trying to make frequency tables, crosstables and model summaries, using bookdown with pdf format mainly, but I am pretty sure my advisor will love I send word documents for revision, so also getting a word output would be awesome. Word output can be achieved producing first the .html file and then opening with Word. **So .html and .pdf output at the same time are desiderables.**

Tables are the main problem because seems impossible to find a productive way to produce frequency, crosstable and summarymodels without too excessive pain in both formats at the same time. Using `knitr` has an added value since it and `kableExtra` provide a set of customizations.

So far I've tried:

1) `sjmisc` / `sjPlot` with the `frq` / `sjt.frq` (deprecated) function
   but only provides html objects as it is said in the [comments of this
   post](https://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2017/03/05/direct-integration-of-sjplot-tables-in-knitr-rmarkdown-documents-rstats/), also has the lack of labels for cross reference in the
   document.

2) `stargazer` package but doesn't have frequency tables available and
   .pdf and .html output at the same time seems impossible to achieve.
   However summary models are pretty good!

3) `descr` package with the `freq` function used inside `kable`:

```
f <- descr::freq(iris$Species, plot = F)
kableExtra::kable(data.frame(f), caption = "Foo")
```

However crosstab output cant be coerced to data.frame while using `crosstab` function.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any update on how to integrate model summaries in a nice way in a HTML document?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for not answering before somehow I missed up your comment. There is a little light at the end! Since using rmarkdown to produce html seems less tricky to produce tables and outputs, at least for me. I started to use the new package `pagedown` to paginate into pdf html documents.

Answer (score 0):

https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/bookdown/index.html

https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/tree/master/docs/bookdown_example

Check out this sample document (I'm still working on this document recently so you may expect some change). Note that you might need the latest dev version of kableExtra and bookdown for some of the formatting features mentioned there.

Comment: Thanks @Hao that was exactly was I was looking for, btw very nice repo and information. I miss some example in the `bookdown_example` with crosstable with count and row/col percentages in the documentation (for example, those produce using `crosstab` function in `descr` package) since it's not been easy to find a package to render using kableExtra and most common tables in reports are frequency tables or crosstables.

Comment: Any news on this @TitoSanz? How did you end up integrating model summary tables?

Comment: I answered in your comment above.

Comment: @Frederick a new way seems to use `pagedown` package. Give it a try!